# ssh keys issue & how to mounts as readonly in devcontainer.json?

Tags: ssh-keys, vscode-remote, ssh-agent, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

i have windows as the host, working with devcontainer **without wsl**, created ssh key with custom name, let say `id_github`. and managed to set ssh-agent auto run, and can use git fetch with ssh key with no problem on the host,

this is my `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile "~/.ssh/id_github"
    ForwardAgent yes
```

but somehow my devcontainer not forwarding ssh automatically ([the doc tells it will](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/sharing-git-credentials#_using-ssh-keys))

that is the **1st question**, can i still make it forward ssh-agent automatically?

otherwise, this is my **2nd question**:
i was looking for a workaround, my option is mounting `.ssh` directory to the container, im not using docker-compose, so in my `devcontainer.json`, i use `mounts` config, but want to mount it as read only, i cannot find any example,

i've tried:

```json
"mounts": [
        "source=~/.ssh,target=/home/vscode/.ssh,readonly,type=bind"
    ]
```

but it is not readonly, `ls -lha ~/.ssh` shows:

```bash
drwxr-sr-x 1 vscode vscode 4.0K Oct 15 10:13 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vscode vscode  124 Oct 15 09:47 config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vscode vscode  133 Oct 15 07:58 id_github
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vscode vscode  133 Oct 15 07:58 id_github.pub
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vscode vscode  828 Oct 14 10:18 known_hosts
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vscode vscode   92 Oct 14 10:16 known_hosts.old
```

and when i invoke it

```bash
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0755 for '/home/vscode/.ssh/id_github' are too open.
```

**3rd question**
i tried `sudo chmod -R 600 ~/.ssh/`, it will change permission on the host too, right?will it be any issue with it? if no, then i also tried to config the command into `devcontainer.json` file, like:

```
"postCreateCommand": {
    "chmod-ssh": "sudo chmod -R 600 ~/.ssh/"
}
```

strangely, it is not affecting, althought the log show it was executed

can you guys help me?
thanks

search for all documentation, still no luck,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The private key should only be read and writeable for the user. all others should have no access permission.

use

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_github
```

to set the correct permissions

Comment: it will change permission on the host too, right?will it be any issue with it?i edited & added more question, thanks

Comment: Yes it will, no there is no issue, because that are the permissions the key file should have